# How to allow Cross Origin Request with Flask CORS correctly?

Tags: python, flask, flask-cors

I'm trying to allow Same Origin request to my Flask app:

this is in my `__init__.py` file:

```
# ... other imports ...
from flask_cors import CORS

cors = CORS()


def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app_settings = os.getenv('APP_SETTINGS')
    app.config.from_object(app_settings)

    from project.api.flakes import flakes_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(flakes_blueprint)
    cors.init_app(flakes_blueprint, resources={r"/flakes": {"origins": "*"}})

    return app
```

According to [docs](https://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/api.html#decorator) this should be sufficient to get it working but I get:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5001/flakes. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)
```

How can I get it working ? I would've thought `{"origins": "*"}` covers everything.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen an example like you have provided using `cors_init_app()`, so cannot comment on why it doesn't work.

However, here is an example of I've used previously that works:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
app.register_blueprint(my_blueprint_module.bp)
```